# Compare array to db and add difference to db

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter.

I'm trying to compare some posted values from a form with entries from a database.

Put simply, i want to check to see if the entry is already in the database, if so ignore the posted data, but if there is no database entry then add to the database.

My thinking was that it shouldn't actually be that hard, but having some issues, and now im completely confused. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

I have an array coming from POST `$assigned_ids`

And i want to compare that with the data from `$assign_data` which is being output from the database.

I've been trying foreach loops, looping over the posted data, and then inside that looping through the database and comparing and adding if neccessary.

It works upto a point, but if there is data coming from the database, its adding multiple entires.

Heres my code, surely im over complicating things?

```
        // posted values foreach - loop through all posted values
    foreach($assigned_ids as $id) {

        if(is_array($assign_data) && count($assign_data) > 0) {

            // query all data in assignments table      
            foreach($assign_data as $key => $value) {

                // is the user id from assignments table in posted id's
                if(in_array($value->user_id, $id)){

                    // if it is, then do the course id's match as well? if so, do nothing, already an entry
                    if($value->course_id == $course_id) {

                        echo "match id and course, do nothing";

                    } else {

                        // else if there isnt an entry for this user for this course, add the entry

                        $add_data = array(
                           'user_id' => $value->user_id,
                           'course_id' => $course_id,
                           'org_id' => $org_id
                        ); 

                        $this->assignment_model->save_org_assignments($add_data);               

                    }
                }  else {


                    // the user id was not in the array from the db, but was in the posted vars, so log in db
                    $add_data = array(
                       'user_id' => $id,
                       'course_id' => $course_id,
                       'org_id' => $org_id
                    ); 

                    $this->assignment_model->save_org_assignments($add_data);                       


                }               
            }
        } else {

            $add_data = array(
               'user_id' => $id,
               'course_id' => $course_id,
               'org_id' => $org_id
            ); 

            $this->assignment_model->save_org_assignments($add_data);               
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems you are using too many loops, but what is causing the double entries is your `do nothing` part. At that moment you should exit the inner `foreach`-loop and continue with the next `id` of the outer `foreach`-loop

Comment: mmm struggling with this. How do i exit the inner foreach loop and then know what id's have been used.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main issue is your array is not properly structured that's why your having a hard time.
My opinion is to predefined your db result after fetching it.

```
function getAssignedData(){
   // its better to get the only field you'll need than to fetch everything
   $result = $this->db->select($field)->get();
   if($result->num_rows()){
      $existing_ids = [];
      foreach($result->result() as $row){
         $existing_ids[] = $row->$field;
      }
      return array_flip($existing_ids);
   }
return FALSE;
```

}

And you can already compare the values like this

```
foreach($assigned_ids as $id)
{
  if(!isset($existing_ids[$id])) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: looks great, I'll give it a try. Although i need 2 columns from the database, as i need to compare user_id and course_id.

Comment: Thanks, It will be the same process and depends how you approach it. Goodluck